# JQuery call to oodle API returns nothing?

Tags: jquery, api, rest

My question is specific to oodle API.

I am trying to call oodle API to get the JSON result like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=sf&category=sale&format=json&mappable=address&jsoncallback=none", function (data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make cross domain request ([XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)). You will need to use JSONP by changing the jsoncallback parameter from your request to `jsoncallback=?` instead of none. [The latest version of jquery will then handle JSONP correctly.](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getJSON_.28using_JSONP.29)

The Oodle API specs mentions jsoncallback: http://developer.oodle.com/listings

Comment: Hi I am using jquery 1.4.2 and tried to do the same thing you told but in Firebug it's showing error.
Don't know what to do?

Here is that code.

$(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("http://api.oodle.com/api?key=TEST&region=sf&category=sale&format=json&mappable=address&jsoncallback=?", function (data) {
                $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
                    //do action
                });
            });
        });

I don't know why it's not working?

Comment: I tried it quiclky and FireBug showed a 500 response from the server. If you look at the response it's a blank page with the Oodle template. Seems to me that the request went through correctly, but Oodle had a problem with it. This could be because key=TEST, but I don't know. Maybe someone at Oodle can help you. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts Adam. I was suspecting and it became truth because I was accessing from localhost it might not get response and when i deployed that test page on my host site it got..so may be because of domain trust. 


thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON("http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=sf&category=sale&format=json&mappable=address&jsoncallback=?", function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

This uses JSONP.  The ? tells jQuery where to insert the name of the callback.  You had none, which is incorrect.  Also, you were missing a right paren.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in oodle api they told that you can give either your name or none. I have given none.

Sorry to ask but which right parenthesis I forgot.

Comment: You can't use none because of the cross-domain restrictions; you need to use JSONP.  The paren was the one closing the method.